# How to find owner of memory address?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, windbg, dump

I am analyzing memory dump with bad_alloc exception and find a significant region of memory what windbg call

```
--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
<unknown>                              4689          3bdc4000 ( 957.766 MB)  48.75%   46.77%
Heap                                   2228          2a1db000 ( 673.855 MB)  34.30%   32.90%
Image                                  1451           b66f000 ( 182.434 MB)   9.29%    8.91%
Stack                                   444           9400000 ( 148.000 MB)   7.53%    7.23%
Free                                   1607           5371000 (  83.441 MB)            4.07%
TEB                                     148            1ad000 (   1.676 MB)   0.09%    0.08%
Other                                   122             c1000 ( 772.000 kB)   0.04%    0.04%
PEB                                       1              3000 (  12.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%
```

And I'm sure that it's native app. I know address of region

```
--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
<unknown>                                    aa20000           5f2e000 (  95.180 MB)
```

and want to find who allocated this memory. How I can do that?

```
0:118> !address aa20000

Usage:                  <unknown>
Base Address:           0aa20000
End Address:            1094e000
Region Size:            05f2e000 (  95.180 MB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000002          PAGE_READONLY
Type:                   00040000          MEM_MAPPED
Allocation Base:        0aa20000
Allocation Protect:     00000002          PAGE_READONLY
```

Heap function don't work with this peace of memory. I asked about dump with gflags enabled, but now I have to work with data I have. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/accessing-memory-by-virtual-address

Comment: "Who allocated the memory?" - some code. You really can't find out without having the stack trace database enabled - and maybe it wouldn't even help for such big allocations, because they are redirected to VirtualAlloc. Memory does not have an "owner" or a "thread" associated with it. Any memory can be accessed by any thread. I think you can only do a code review and look for allocations that could become that large.

Comment: Your process has 957+673+182+148=1960 MB of memory allocated and there are only 83 MB free, scattered into 1607 pieces. Almost every allocation will give you bad_alloc. Port your app to 64 bit or at least make it Large Address Aware, but yes, also make sure you don't have memory leaks of 95 MB.

Comment: That memory region looks like a memory mapped file.

Comment: Thank you all, this was a single case and it will be great to solve this case. So I asked testers to reproduce defect with additional flags. May be after I will find the cause